# Truffle contract bytecode not updating with library address

Tags: solidity, truffle, library

After deploying a library using truffle, I want to compile a contract and use the library address inside its generated bytecode. Now inside the contract bytecode I get something like `_DateTime______`.

I want to be able to integrate truffle inside a web3 blockchain-api, that uses the command `contract.deploy({data: bytecode})`, but I can not get the library address inside the bytecode, and the request is always crashing.

I am able to do this if I compile manually (using `solc`) , the library, then get the address and use the flag `--link (+ the library address)` in the solc command, when compiling the other contract, but I want to find out how to do this automatically using truffle. Thank you.